Looking for a book where a young girl finds and hides a baby dragon, and the girl's guardian is possessed by a henchman
A long time ago I read a book I can now barely remember. The story involved a baby dragon that gets sent from a fantasy world into the real world and gets found by the main character. In the mc's world there just so happened to be a card collecting club, and the dragon was one of the cards. The mc tries to hide the baby dragon while the main villain tries to find it for some reason. At some point the mc's caretaker (can't remember if they were an aunt or sister, etc) gets possessed by the main villain's minion to do the villain's bidding. I also think the cover had a dragon on it, but again, I can barely remember. I hope someone can help me figure out what book this was please?
I don't remember exactly when I read it, but I believe it was some time before 2015. I believe it was something like a novel (definitely not a short story, but not a hundred chapters long if I remember correctly). Something between an adult story and a child's story.
The copy I read was in English, but I don't know if it was translated or originally in English.
I definitely got it from a library, but whether it was a school or simply a Public library I can't say for certain, except that it was in the US somewhere.

Hi and welcome to Literature Stack Exchange. To make this work easier to identify, please add any information you have of the kind listed at the tag wiki for identification requests. This includes details about where and when you read it (how long ago is "a long time ago"?), what the publication date seemed to be, etc. Please edit your question to add these details, don't provide them in the comments. Thanks!

Thanks for the edits. How old was the mc? If you remember, please edit again to add that info. If you don't, that's fine, you've provided plenty of helpful details such that someone who has read the book will recognize it.

hey Verbose, sorry for the late response... i think the mc was young, i don't know exactly how old, but  i definitely know they were a young character, i think it was one of those kinds of stories where some kid or teen finds a magical macguffin and all of a sudden have to save a magicall world or something, but i honestly can't remember much..

This sounds very much like Hatching Magic by Ann Downer. Published in 2003 it is certainly consistent with being read in 2015 ("a long time ago ;), and weighing in at about 250 pages it is a fairly short novel, aimed at children.
The main character of the story is a teenage girl named Theodora Oglethorpe. Her mother had died some years before, and her father leaves to go to Laos for research (he is a biologist), so she is left in the care of a nanny, Michelle Kolodney, usually known as "Mikko".
Theodora plays a card collecting game called "Wizards and Wyverns". When she finds a truly magical card, she inadvertently uses it to summon a baby wyvern from a magical realm. Its owner, Gideon, and his evil rival Kobold travel from there to Boston, Massachusetts in the twenty-first century to recover it. In their search, Kobold's demon assistant, Febrys, indeed possesses Mikko:

Kobold's orders had been very clear: enter the Oglethorpe household,
possess the human woman Michelle Kolodney, and gain the confidence of
the Oglethorpe child with the aim of obtaining the wyvern trump

the "wyvern trump" being the magical card.
The book is available for free loan from the Internet Archive.

Holy sh- that's it! THANK YOU SO MUCH!!!

Glad to help Lilith
